# JavaFX: Binding and weak listener

Tags: java, javafx

From [Javadoc for `bind()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-):

> Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak
>   listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and
>   stopped from being updated.

Now consider that I have two properties `ObjectProperty<Foo> shortLived` residing in `ShortLivedObject` and `ObjectProperty<Foo> longLived` residing in `LongLivedObject`.

I am binding them like this:

```
longLivedObject.longLivedProperty().bind(shortLivedObject.shortLivedProperty());
```

Because binding uses weak listener, so if `shortLivedObject` is garbage collected, `shortLived` property would be garbage collected as well. So, does that means that `longLived` property is still bound, but it will never be updated? Does that leave `longLived` property in a bound state (making further binding impossible), but does nothing?

Comment: I think what the JavaDoc says is that the listener of the `longLivedProperty`-- which is used to listen to changes of the shortLivedObject-- may be garbage collected as it uses `WeakReference`, right?. 
Unless you have a strong reference to the `longLivedProperty` which will prevent its listener from being garbage collected.
Hence, the JavaDoc is not saying that the `shortLivedProperty` will be garbage collected. So why are you expecting `shortLivedProperty` to be garbage collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, does that means that longLived property is still bound, but it
>   will never be updated?

Assuming that the `shortLivedProperty` has been garbage collected, the `shortLivedProperty` will never be invalidated again. As a result, the listener of the `longLived` will never be called and updated again.

> Does that leave longLived property in a bound state (making further
>   binding impossible), but does nothing?

You should always be able to `bind` a property to a **new** observable regardless of the binding state as the old observable property will be removed/unbound for you:

```
public void bind(final ObservableValue<? extends T> newObservable) {
    if (newObservable == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot bind to null");
    }

    if (!newObservable.equals(this.observable)) {
        unbind();
        observable = newObservable;
        if (listener == null) {
            listener = new Listener(this);
        }
        observable.addListener(listener);
        markInvalid();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found something interesting while I looked for the source codes. If `this.observable` is the other property that the current property is listening for changes, then wouldn't the current property be holding a strong reference of the other property? So they made the listener weak but kept the reference of the other property strong...

Comment: that's why I asked you "why are you expecting `shortLivedProperty` to be garbage collected"? As far as I understand this should not happen because shortLivedProperty is at least strongly reachable from the `longLivedProperty` as you described.

Comment: Well, the Javadoc says this: `This means the bound property can be garbage collected`. After seeing source codes, this claim turns out to be a blatant lie.

Comment: The _bound property_ refers to the `longLivedProperty` since `longLivedProperty` is bound to `shortLivedProperty`. Indeed, `longLivedProperty` may be garbage collected if it is weakly reachable. That is, if you don't have a strong reference to the `longLivedProperty`